# Foreign key column sorting

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo grid with ForeignKey column with sorting. By default this column is sorted by value but we need it to be sorted by text. Could anyone provide please an example of doing it using ASP.NET Wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

I found the trick was to implement `IComparable` on the foreign key object, which then sorts by the text name instead of the id in the Kendo grid:

```
public class MyForeignKeyModel : IComparable<MyForeignKeyModel>
{
    public int ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set;}

    public int CompareTo(MyForeignKeyModel compareTo)
    {
        return String.Compare(Name, compareTo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

All the other solutions mentioned by users and Telerik look much more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Reponse by [**Atanas Korchev (Admin, Kendo UI)**](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4147227-grid-sorting-foreignkey-column) We can’t support this in all cases because the data source won’t have all data (it usually has just the foreign key which is the value)

You can use Grouping if that helps to some extend.