# Sorting By Foreign key Column Text not value in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

the sorting in mvc kendo grid foreign column sort by values not text 
[image]

the code is

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid( _
    Of cls.ProductSpecificationM).Name("Grid").Columns(
    Sub(i)
            i.Bound(Function(p) p.ProductSpecification_ID).Hidden(True)

            i.ForeignKey(Function(p) p.Attribute_ID_FK, DirectCast(ViewBag.Attributes, System.Collections.IEnumerable), "Attribute_ID", "Attribute_Name").EditorTemplateName("_Attribute_ID_FK").Title("Name")
            i.ForeignKey(Function(p) p.AttributeValue_ID_FK, DirectCast(ViewBag.AttributeValues, System.Collections.IEnumerable), "AttributeValue_ID", "AttributeValue_Name").EditorTemplateName("_AttributeValue_ID_FK").Title("Value")
            i.Command(Sub(w)
                              w.Destroy()
                      End Sub)
    End Sub).ToolBar(Sub(k)
                             k.Create() : k.Save()

                     End Sub).Editable(Function(e) e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).Pageable(Function(i) i.Input(True).PageSizes({10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400}).Refresh(True)).Sortable().Filterable().DataSource( _
                                                       Function(p) p.Ajax().PageSize(50).Batch(True).ServerOperation(False).Model(Sub(i)
                                                                                                                                          i.Id(Function(p2) p2.ProductSpecification_ID)
                                                                                                                                          i.Field(Function(p2) p2.Item_ID_Fk).DefaultValue(ViewBag.Id)
                                                                                                                                          i.Field(Function(p2) p2.AttributeValue_ID_FK).DefaultValue(1)
                                                                                                                                          i.Field(Function(p2) p2.Attribute_ID_FK).DefaultValue(1)
                                                                                                                                  End Sub) _
                                                             .Read("EditingInline_Read", "Products", New With {.id = ViewBag.Id}) _
                                                             .Update(Function(u) u.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Products")) _
                                                             .Destroy(Function(update) update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Products")) _
                                                             .Create(Function(update) update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Products"))).Events(Function(e) e.Edit("edit"))
```

**how Can I sort by the column text ?**

Comment: They added sample how-to in the docs http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/foreign-key-column-sorting-by-text

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456439/foreign-key-column-sorting#52476736), it seemed to work well for Kendo grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like kendo doesn't support it. Need to come up with some other solution.

Reponse by [**Atanas Korchev (Admin, Kendo UI)**](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4147227-grid-sorting-foreignkey-column) We can’t support this in all cases because the data source won’t have all data (it usually has just the foreign key which is the value)

You can use Grouping if that helps to some extend. [**Grouping column in Kendo**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html)